# BIOS doesn't recognize USB and is being really weird?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

I have an Asus X550C notebook and I've been trying to format/reinstall Windows 7 on it.

I made a bootable USB and I've been trying to boot from it but it just doesn't show on the boot options list?

And my BIOS is missing many features as it says in the e-manual of the notebook.

I tried updating it but when I choose "Start Easy Flash" nothing happens..

Another thing I tried is installing plop boot manager, but when I get into boot manager it only shows me Windows 7, no plop.

Note I can only access my laptop in safe mode.

BIOS version is 2.15.1227 (2012?)

Answer (score 1):

> I made a bootable USB and I've been trying to boot from it but it just doesn't show on the boot options list?

- Double check that the BIOS has the ability to boot from USB devices. Not showing up may indicate this, but you may also need to cycle through some device listings in the boot order.
- Make sure that the boot order favors the USB (make sure any option to boot from USB in the BIOS is listed before any option to boot from hard disk in the device boot order.)
- Double check you actually have a bootable USB device (i.e. you set the boot media up correctly).
- Double check that the boot media isn't failing. The last time I had a hard time with a USB drive being recognized, it was because it died shortly thereafter.

> [M]y BIOS is missing many features as it says in the e-manual of the notebook.

You may be looking in the wrong places or you may (more likely) have the wrong manual. A quick Google search revealed there is at least an Asus X550CA and Asus X550CC. Double check which laptop you have.

> I tried updating [the BIOS] but when I choose "Start Easy Flash" nothing happens.

My experience is that when manufacturer's tools like this fail to find updates, it is often because there are no updates (you already have the latest firmware for your hardware or they have stopped supporting the device directly).

> Another thing I tried is installing plop boot manager, but when I get into boot manager it only shows me Windows 7, no plop.

Apologies but I don't understand this step. I know what boot mangers typically do but I am at a loss about what you were trying to accomplish.

> Note I can only access my laptop in safe mode.

This is another puzzler for me. Safe mode seems to imply you haven't formatted anything yet? Apologies again, but I am not sure what the relevance is.

***Suggestion***

Assuming you have a a working DVD-ROM drive, make a bootable CD/DVD rather than using USB media. My experience is that this path is much more reliable and much less headache prone than booting anything from USB.